# Regular expression to validate FQDN

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, regex

I am trying to use following Regular Expression to validate FQDN in Javascript. This works fine in C#. But Page throws 403 error when used in javascript. What am i doing wrong?

```
 if (!fqdn.match(/(?=^.{1,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d|-)[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.?)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,})$)/)) 
    {
        alert("Not a valid FQDN");               
        return false;           
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex uses a [negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<!-)`, and those aren't supported by JavaScript.

You can rewrite your regex to match exactly the same way without lookbehinds:

```
/(?=^.{1,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d|-)[a-z0-9-]{0,62}[a-z0-9]\.?)+(?:[a-z]{2,})$)/i
```

I'm not so sure if the logic behind the regex really is correct for validating a FQDN, though, but that's a different problem. For example, the optional dot makes the regex susceptible to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). This is a good way to [crash your browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17998721/20670).

Comment: thank u for the quick reply. I have been searching all over to find a correct validation for the format and this was one i found in most people suggesting. Btw what is "i" at the end of the expression you updated?

Comment: Here are the other two i found. @nd one doesnt check for length though.
1.      (?=^.{1,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d+\.|-)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.?)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,})$)   
2.       \b((?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63}\.)(xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,63}\b

Comment: `/i` makes the regex case-insensitive. As for your other question, I'll take a look at the question you wrote yesterday and will try to answer that.